# Help - android databases

Tags: android, database, sqlite, simultaneous

I have an application which downloads contacts periodically (using a service and asyn task), but at the same time I read the contacts which were already downloaded.

My problem is, when I'm downloading the contacts, I try to read the database, the application crashes.

Could someone explain to me how I can read and write to the database simultaneously.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using transactions?. I mean: db.beginTransaction();. let me know and i can give your more details on that

Comment: Yes I am. That is only when I am writing to the database cause it's a lot of records, about 5000-10000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you try **getReadableDatabase()** of database helper only for reading and **getWritableDatabase()** of the same for sake of writing. may be this would do the trick.

I hope you have implmented onUpdate method correctly, this could result in some serious currupt data.

Comment: Hmm ok I will try that, seems like a good idea. where do I implement the onUpdate method?

Comment: Also what do you think if I create two databases, one to read and one to write. Is that a waste of resources? I'm pretty sure it is, but it seems like the best way of doing it without letting the app crash